# html and css wont link once placed in folder

Tags: html, css

my css and html linked just fine when they were just all on my desktop but once I placed them in folders for proper file structure all the images broke and the css no longer links I made sure all the href's were proper just none of the images or the css are working anymore.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML5>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <head>
        <title >Space Cube</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="mart145final/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        <img src="mart145final/images/space-cube.png" style="width:200px;height:100px;">
        </header>
```

Comment: 1) Are you spinning up a local fileserver, or just using the OS filesystem? 2) Have you opened the devtools in your browser to see what exactly the error you are getting is? (404, wrong mimetype, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having the css folder and images folder inside the same location as the html file. Then, remove the "mart145final/" prefix from your link and image strings.

(Your html is currently saying "to find this image, go to the folder this html file is in, then go to mart145final and look for the css and images folder. I suspect the html file is inside your mart145final folder. In that case, just change the html references.)

Comment: Thanks a bunch that did it!